# Choropleth maps in R using leaflet package

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to create interactive Choropleth maps in R using leaflet package. 
my final output should be like, when the user clicks any of the US state then a popup should be displayed with state name and the magnitude value for the corresponding state. 

Below is the code that I am using. The issue I am facing is that, whenever I click on an any estate (except Alaska) the popup shows incorrect state name. 
example if I click on the Florida state, the popup shows as Idaho.

Someone please explain what could be the potential issue that is causing this type of behavior.

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
us_states <- readOGR(dsn="cb_2016_us_state_500k.kml")           
plot(us_states)
s <- read.csv("us_state_mag_values.csv")

popup1 <- paste0("<span style='color: #7f0000'><strong>us state values</strong></span>",
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>Stae: </strong></span>", 
                 s$state, 
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>relative amount: </strong></span>", 
                 s$mag
)

palette <- colorBin(c('#fee0d2',  
                      '#fcbba1',
                      '#fc9272',
                      '#fb6a4a',
                      '#ef3b2c',
                      '#cb181d',
                      '#a50f15',
                      '#67000d'), 
                    bins = c(1,10,20,25,30,35,40,47))


mymap <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
  addPolygons(data = us_states, 
              fillColor = ~palette(s$mag),
              fillOpacity = 0.6,       
              color = "darkgrey",      
              weight = 1.5,            
              popup = popup1)%>%
  addLegend(position = 'topleft', 
            colors = c('#fee0d2',
                       '#fcbba1',
                       '#fc9272',
                       '#fb6a4a',
                       '#ef3b2c',
                       '#cb181d',
                       '#a50f15',
                       '#67000d'), 
            labels = c('0%',"","","","","","",'100%'), 
            opacity = 0.6,      
            title = "relative<br>magnitude") 
print(mymap)
```

[the KML file can be found here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/kml/kml_state.html)

My dataset of US states and corresponding magnitude values look like this
[image: My dataset of US states and corresponding magnitude values look like this]

**EDIT**
My Output visualization is pasted below. Notice the popup with incorrect state name.
[image: Output visualization]

Comment: Probably a mismatch between the sorting of the two data sets... Hwo about merging the two data frames into one?

Comment: @TimSalabim I have only 1 dataframe with two columns. one column for state names and other for magnitude values. Have also pasted my visualization output in edit section.

Comment: But you also have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from reading the .kml file with `readOGR`. A quick look at the .kml file shows that it also has the state names so you could merge the two by that. It might be easier to use `library(sf)` instead of `rgdal` to read the kml file and do the merging

Comment: @TimSalabim Thanks for pointing out that. Now it works as expected. Also thanks for introducing me to `sf` package. It is much faster than `rgdal`