# How to create a choropleth on a leaflet Map R

Tags: r, leaflet, choropleth

**Problem**

I have loaded in the shapefile of the UK, no issues. Lets call this `FILE1`.
I also have a data frame file with 2 columns: Longitude, Latitude. lets call this `FILE2`. I am trying to plot the coordinates of `FILE2` onto the shapefile map of `FILE1` and create a choropleth map

I am also receiving the following error:

> Error in polygonData.default(data) : 
>     Don't know how to get path data from object of class tbl_df

**CODE**

I have taken the code from this question: [Choropleth maps in R using leaflet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434898/choropleth-maps-in-r-using-leaflet-package) 
and adapted it to suit my data

```
#Plot the Leaflet map----
mymap <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
  addPolygons(data = coords, #This is data frame of U.K long and lat
              fillColor = ~palette(file$TotalByPostcode), 
              fillOpacity = 0.6,       
              color = "darkgrey",      
              weight = 1.5,            
              popup = popup1)%>%
  addLegend(position = 'topleft', 
            colors = c('#fee0d2',
                       '#fcbba1',
                       '#fc9272',
                       '#fb6a4a',
                       '#ef3b2c',
                       '#cb181d',
                       '#a50f15',
                       '#67000d'), 
            labels = c('0',"","","","","","",'100'), 
            opacity = 0.6,      
            title = "Totals") 

print(map)
```

Here is my data frame:

[image: Data Frame]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not have your data in my hand. But I guess that you misunderstood one thing about the leaflet package. If you type `?leaflet` in your R Console, you would see the following information in the help page.

> a data object. Currently supported objects are matrices, data frames, spatial objects from the sp package (SpatialPoints, SpatialPointsDataFrame, Polygon, Polygons, SpatialPolygons, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, Line, Lines, SpatialLines, and SpatialLinesDataFrame), and spatial data frames from the sf package.

This tells you what kind of data objects leaflet can take. Keeping this point in your mind, and let's check the following two cases.

## CASE1: SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

In this case, I downloaded a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using the raster package, which is called `UK` in my code. I also create a dummy data frame called `mydf`. In `addPolygons()`, I am using a spatial object. A map nicely came out.

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

# Get UK polygon data
UK <- getData("GADM", country = "GB", level = 2)

### Create dummy data
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(place = unique(UK$NAME_2),
                   value = sample.int(n = 1000000, size = n_distinct(UK$NAME_2), replace = TRUE))

### Create five colors for fill
mypal <- colorQuantile(palette = "RdYlBu", domain = mydf$value, n = 5, reverse = TRUE)

leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = UK,
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~mypal(mydf$value),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Value: ", mydf$value, "<br>")) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = mypal, values = mydf$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 1)
```

[image]

## CASE2: tbl_df

Now let's see what happens with a regular data frame. I am not sure what kind of data you exactly have. But, one thing for sure is that it has `tbl_df` in class. I wanted to make sure that an object has `tbl_df` in class. So I did the following. I converted the polygon data (i.e., UK) to a data frame. Let's check the class.

```
x <- as_data_frame(fortify(UK))
class(x)
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Before we move on, I want to mention again that you cannot draw a polygon with a normal data frame including one with `tbl_df` in class. This is what I said at the beginning of this post. Hence, the following code, which I just changed `UK` to `x`, returned an error message.

```
leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = x,
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~mypal(mydf$value)) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = mypal, values = mydf$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 1)
```

> Error in polygonData.default(data) : 
>     Don't know how to get path data from object of class tbl_df

I hope this demonstration clears up your mind. The lesson to take is: Use a spatial class object from the sp or sf package. In your case, you would perhaps want to use `FILE1` in `addPolygons()`. Make sure that it is a spatial object. If you have a right file, you will see polygons on top of the tile map.

Comment: thanks, i got the following error for case 1: Error in cut.default(x, binsToUse, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique

Comment: @user1 I cannot reproduce the error message. Are you replicating my codes with my sample data?

Comment: I am using your code and substituting ‘mydf’ with my own dataset

Comment: My dataset is the same class as your ‘mydf’

Comment: @user1 Since you use your own data, my code is not working. You need to make your own adjustment.

Comment: Shall I add my dataset to the question ? Will that help ?

Comment: @user1 Yeah, you want to do that. Otherwise SO users have no idea of what is happening on your side.

Comment: Done. Added the data frame to the question

Comment: @user1 Let me have a bit of time.

Comment: i think we need to wrap the domain in unique? but even having done that, the map does not come out as expected

Comment: @user1 Two things for you. 1) You need to use `dput()` to create a data for SO users. Showing a screen shot would not work; that requires the users to type all data for you. 2) Your data is completely different from mine. In my data, I used the areas names (i.e., NAME_2) in the SPDF, UK. You have postal code, which is not in my data. You could do `colorQuantile(palette = "RdYlBu", domain = mydf$ToTall, n = 5, reverse = TRUE)`, but this won't work when you draw a map. You need to have exact the same names of places in the polygon and the other data.

Comment: @user1 In short, if you want to test with your own data, you need 1) a polygon data related to UK postal codes, and 2) You need a data frame that contains exact the same postal codes from the polygon data and a numeric variable (e.g., ToTall). Unless you have these, you would not be able to apply my codes to your case.

Comment: Thank You. i realised that as soon as you sent this comment. I changed the postcodes to reflect the regions in the UK GADM polygons, and the map has now plotted nicely!    one final thing - how can i save this as a webpage to allow others to view?

Comment: @user1 That is out of my hand. I have not done that before. You could use the shiny package, for example.

Comment: cannot use shiny as need to develop secure company servers to upload the shinyApp to. Can i change the legend to have custom labels?

Comment: @user1 Like what kind of labels? If you want, check `?addLegend`. You can find more information. Or check [**here**](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html).

Comment: as in the percentage labels next to each colour label. i want it to be a text string instead of a percentage

Comment: @user1 OK. Let me see if I can do that for you with my example above.

Comment: @user1 I played around and found a way. It is really late here. So I need to sleep now. I leave the following working code for you. `leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = UK,
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            color = brewer.pal(5,"RdYlBu")) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", values = mydf$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 1,
          colors = brewer.pal(5,"RdYlBu"), 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))`.