# How to assign popup on map polygon that corresponds with the country R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, r-leaflet

I am trying to write a script that would allow people to click on a country then a popup would appear and show the country's name and corresponding value. I have successfully created the map and the boundaries of each country, however when you click on, for example Russia, the popup would show India. Below is a simplified version of the script:

```
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

countries <- c("Australia", "South Africa", "India", "Mexico", "USA", "Russia")

values <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

bounds <- map("world", countries, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)


map <- leaflet(data) %>%
       addTiles() %>%
       addPolygons(data = bounds, group = "Countries", 
                   color = "red", 
                    weight = 2,
                    popup = paste("Country: ", countries, "<br>", "Value: ", values, "<br>"),
                    fillOpacity = 0.1,
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                        weight = 2,
                                                        bringToFront = TRUE))

map
```

The map is generated using the `leaflet` package in R. Any solutions or advice would be welcome, I am sure it is a simple error that I am making somewhere.

Comment: If you replace `popup = countries` to `popup = ~names`, you will see the names of the countries. If you really have to show the names exactly you specified in `countries`, you need to do some string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you that works. But what if I want to append some other information as well? Like info on the region based on data I acquired?

Comment: I cannot see how you want to have popups. Do you wanna show country and region together?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear. If I click on Russia it should have a popup showing the country, population size, average temperatures etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I leave two options for you. If you just want to show the country names as they are in `bounds` (e.g., Australia:Melville Island), you need to change `popup = countries` to `popup = ~names`.

```
map1 <- leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
        addPolygons(data = bounds, group = "Countries", 
                    color = "red", 
                    weight = 2,
                    popup = ~names,
                    fillOpacity = 0.1,
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                        weight = 2,
                                                        bringToFront = TRUE))
```

[image]

If you want to just have the country names as you specified in `countries`, you want to manipulate `names` using `gsub()`, for example. Here I removed all characters from `:` to the end for each name.

```
map2 <- leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
        addPolygons(data = bounds, group = "Countries", 
                    color = "red", 
                    weight = 2,
                    popup = ~gsub(x = names, pattern = ":.*$", replacement = ""),
                    fillOpacity = 0.1,
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                        weight = 2,
                                                        bringToFront = TRUE))
```

[image]

**EXTRA**

The OP added one more thing to his question. Here is my idea. If you have two things to show in popups, you can do the following. You add `value` to `bounds` and create popups.

```
# Add values to bounds. 

set.seed(111)
bounds$value <- sample.int(n = 1000, size = 301, replace = TRUE)

map3 <- leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
        addPolygons(data = bounds, group = "Countries", 
                    color = "red", 
                    weight = 2,
                    popup = paste("Country: ", bounds$names, "<br>",
                                  "Value: ", bounds$value, "<br>"),
                    fillOpacity = 0.1,
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                        weight = 2,
                                                        bringToFront = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works well. But what if, for example, I have the list of countries and with them I also want information regarding data I obtained to also be shown in the popup. data <- c(20, 30, 33, 12, 34, 55)

Comment: @RoelofCoertze Have a look of [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571337/how-to-create-a-choropleth-on-a-leaflet-map-r), for example.

Comment: please see edited version, the post you linked helped, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: @RoelofCoertze I gotta go to bed soon since it is pretty late here. One thing you want to realize is that I did not use the vector, `countries`. I rather used `names` which is a part of `bounds`. If you have `value` in `bounds`, I think my approach in the link would probably work. Otherwise, you would need to create a data frame including the country names (i.e., `names`) and values. In short, using a vector like `countries` and `values` is not a right way.

Comment: No problem I will try that. I am not a trained programmer, just a humble biologist so this is pretty new.

Comment: @RoelofCoertze I added the extra thing. Have a look. Good luck with your work.

Comment: @RoelofCoertze Pleasure to help you.