# maps::map() returning region names instead of country names

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

I am trying to create a pop up for each country on a leaflet map showing the name of the country and a number. I have though come upon a similar problem in stack exchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512240/how-to-assign-popup-on-map-polygon-that-corresponds-with-the-country-r-leaflet).

```
country <- c("Austria", "Germany", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Croatia")
# Wanted only five countries
bounds <- map("world", country, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
bounds$value <- c(300, 4, 8, 1, 8)

# Producing leaflet map
leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
      addPolygons(data = bounds, group = "Countries", 
                  color = "red", 
                  weight = 2,
                  popup = paste("Country: ", bounds$names, "<br>",
                                "Value: ",bounds$value, "<br>"),
                  fillOpacity = 0.1,
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                      weight = 2,
                                                      bringToFront = TRUE))
```

When the map is produced the pop ups are displaying the wrong numbers I then proceeded to check out how `bounds$names` looks like and I see that the first five names of the countries are the following:

"Austria"              "Germany:Usedom"       "Germany:Fehmarn"      "Germany:Rugen"   "Germany:4"

The map itself is still showing popups for the countries I want including Austria, Germany, Hungary, Slovakia, and Croatia but just with the wrong numbers. I don't know why `map()` produced cities for Germany although the top five countries in `country[1:5]` are "Austria"  "Germany"  "Slovakia" "Hungary"  "Croatia"

How do stop `map()` from giving me cities and not all the countries I want. If anyone knows a simpler way of doing this I would be happy to know.

Comment: Can you provide part of your data (using `dput()`) to be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I provided some fake data in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an argument `exact = TRUE` to the call of `maps::map()`, this solves the problem.

```r
library(leaflet)

country <- c("Austria", "Germany", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Croatia")

bounds <- maps::map("world", country, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE, exact = TRUE)

bounds$value <- c(300, 4, 8, 1, 8)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
  addPolygons(data = bounds, 
              group = "Countries", 
              color = "red", 
              weight = 2,
              popup = paste("Country: ", bounds$names, "<br>",
                            "Value: ", bounds$value, "<br>"),
              fillOpacity = 0.1,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "black", 
                                                  weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE))
```

Also creating the HTML labels separately and checking them before passing them to `leaflet` might help in finding the problems...